# WD HDD physically damaged, what can I use to recover the data on OSX?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, data-recovery, hdd

I have a physically damaged HDD that can still be detected by disk utility, but I cannot access the files inside. I tried using Data Rescue 3 but the UI was very clunky and I always end up having to restart the computer for it to work. It did manage to scan it once and recover many files, but not some specific file types I was looking for. But due to the clunky UI I couldn't scan it again.

Any programs that are reliable and *known* to recover files from damaged hard drives ?

Note :

- It is connected externally via USB.
- The HDD was on a Windows Desktop, but using the mac to read it

Comment: It's not a duplicate @Mark

Comment: Why the other question iOS how to get data off a dead disk - which is what you are asking, the answers will be the same

Comment: @mark This is exactly why I stopped posting here... The answers in the other topic did not help me. You guys always close down topics even if "duplicates" did not have satisfying answers ....

Comment: @bmike This is exactly why I stopped posting here... The answers in the other topic did not help me. You guys always close down topics even if "duplicates" did not have satisfying answers ....

Comment: So you need to explain why those answers do not work

Comment: The reopening of questions at are closed and on hold are quite painless. Just edit your post to explain if it is different than the linked question or edit / bounty the dupe. We try hard to have the information in one place if you are just re asking an old question.